# Apache Shiro - SecurityManager from where is obtained?

Tags: java, apache

Is SecurityManager a single instance created at startup and referenced in the ThreadContext for all requests? Or in ThreadContext there's a new instance of SecurityManager?

I cannot understand why SecurityManager is taken from ThreadContext in SecurityUtils. This class have an static SecurityManager and it says that is not recommended to be static at least if it where single application (Desktop). I am trying to understand it under web development.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is created at startup, here is a Java example:

```
Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new   IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
```

[Shiro Tutorial](http://shiro.apache.org/tutorial.html)